# Connecting to Cloud SQL from Cloud Run via cloud-sql-proxy with IAM login enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-iam, cloud-sql-proxy

I would like to connect to a Cloud SQL instance from Cloud Run, using a service account. The connection used to be created within the VPC and we would just provide a connection string with a `user` and a `password` to our PostgreSQL client. But now we want the authentication to be managed by Google Cloud IAM, with the service account associated with the Cloud Run service.

On my machine, I can use the `enable_iam_login` argument to use my own service account. The command to run the Cloud SQL proxy would look like this:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=[PROJECT-ID]:[REGION]:[INSTANCE] \
-enable_iam_login -credential_file=${HOME}/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
```

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to use the IAM authentication method to run the Cloud SQL Proxy from Cloud Run, I can just provide an instance name. Has anyone face this problem before?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to configure Cloud Run's use of the Cloud SQL proxy to do this for you.

If you are using Java, Python, or Go, [there are language specific connectors you can use from Cloud Run.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-connectors) These all have the option to use IAM DB AuthN as part of them.

Comment: Hey there, is this limitation still exist? Thanks :)

Comment: @FuyangLiu yes.

Comment: Issue tracker for cloud run supporting iam auth: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203133309

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using NodeJS on Cloud Run :

- you can't enable the `-enable_iam_login` option in Cloud Run (cf accepted answer), which means you have to use a connector.
- AFAIK, there is no NodeJS connector right now. Edit : [Google is working on a NodeJS connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector) !

Which means you have 2 options :

- write a connector yourself (good luck) or wait for Google to do it
- use built-in database authentication for now.