# Connecting Cloud Run Flask app to Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL via SQL Auth Proxy always throwing an error

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, flask-sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

As the title says, I have a Flask app, running on cloud run that I am attempting to connect to Cloud SQL where I have a postgres instance.

After much debugging I stripped down the app to the bare minimum and I receive the following error in the Cloud Run logs:
`Cloud SQL instance "<instance-name>" is not reachable. Deploy a new revision adding the Cloud SQL connection. See documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run`

But I do have a cloud SQL connection configured.

This is then followed by a long python stacktrace as we'd expect if there is no db connection, which I don't think is useful so I haven't included it here.

**TL;DR**: I have a feeling the issue is that I'm using the incorrect `DB_HOST` IP address in order to make sure SQL Auth proxy is used, what should I be using in the `DB_URI` string?

I followed the steps from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693241/how-to-securely-connect-to-cloud-sql-from-cloud-run) post which is essentially the same as the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run).

A summary of what I did:

- I have a PostgreSQL instance with a public IP
- I made a new table
- I deployed my code using `gcloud run deploy`
- I added the `Cloud SQL Client` role to the service account used for the cloud run service.
- I made a revision in which I added the Cloud SQL connection to the cloud run service as detailed in the [docs above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693241/how-to-securely-connect-to-cloud-sql-from-cloud-run)
- I also added `DB_USER`, `DB_HOST`, `DB_PASS` etc as environment variables in a revision.

I tested this locally using the SQL Auth Proxy and it works as expected. In the terminal running the auth proxy I can see a line `New connection for "<instance-connection-name>"` so it works locally. I used `127.0.0.1` as the `DB_HOST` when running locally. For context my DB URI is different on my local machine because I'm running Windows and I can't use unix sockets.

In cloud run I have tried setting `DB_HOST` to both `127.0.0.1` and the DB public IP address, both produce the same error.

my `./run.py` file that I use to run the app.

```
from sampleapp import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8000)))
```

my `./sampleapp/__init__.py` which contains app instantiation.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

LOCAL_TESTING = bool(os.environ.get("LOCAL_TESTING", False)) # Set to True if running locally

DB_USER = os.getenv('DB_USER')
DB_PASS = os.getenv('DB_PASS')
DB_NAME = os.getenv('DB_NAME')
DB_HOST = os.getenv('DB_HOST')
DB_PORT = os.getenv('DB_PORT')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['DEBUG'] = os.getenv('DEBUG', False)

if LOCAL_TESTING == True:
    # This is what runs on my local machine
    print("Using tcp connection to db")
    DB_URI = f'postgresql+pg8000://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASS}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}'
else:
    # This run on cloud run
    print("Using unix_sock connection to db")
    db_socket_dir = os.environ.get("DB_SOCKET_DIR", "/cloudsql")
    DB_URI = f'postgresql+pg8000://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASS}@/{DB_NAME}?unix_sock={db_socket_dir}/{DB_INSTANCE_NAME}/.s.PGSQL.5432'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_URI
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from sampleapp import routes
```

The DB URIs above are taken from the code snippets in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run) but instead of using `sqlalchemy.create_engine()` I'm using flask-sqlalchemy and instead of `sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create()` I'm just making my own URI string.

The excecution line from my `./Dockerfile`:

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 run:app
```

From my cloud run logs I can see that my routes work fine up until the point I try to access the DB.

From reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70024078/connecting-to-cloud-sql-from-cloud-run-via-cloud-sql-proxy-with-iam-login-enable) and the docs on [the Cloud SQL Python connector](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-connectors#python) I should be using the connector code from google but I don't know how to use this in the context of `flask_sqlalchemy` because google always uses standard sqlalchemy. I couldn't work out how to assign the `engine` object in google's code snippets to the flask-sqlalchemy `SQLAlchemy` object that I am using for `db`.

Apologies for the long question I have been trying to debug this for a long time to no avail. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What’s in DB_INSTANCE_NAME on Cloud Run?

Comment: You are setting `DB_URI` under local testing but `DB_URL` under the else statement. Is this intentional?  I believe you can also set the `sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL` object directly for `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']`

Comment: @WietseVenema apologies that's an unused variable I thought I would need. Now edited out.

Comment: @kurtisvg In the code it is all URL I just changed it to URI to stick with convention for this post and I must have missed one. Isn't that what I am already doing? I had assumed the `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']` get's passed to the `sqlalchemy.engine` object. DO you know of any documentation I can read with instructions for that?

Comment: Here's the documentation for [flask-sqlalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#configuration). It looks like the regular way to configure the engine directly is with the `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS` which would let you use the Cloud SQL python connector.  Alternatively, I think you can set `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` equal to a `sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL` object that's initialized like in the current documentation.

Comment: Building on the previous comments and to discard other causes, can you deploy the minimal service using standard SQLAlchemy as shown in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#command-line) for connecting Cloud Run to Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 4):

I made a bare-bones app deployed on Cloud Run resembling your setup. For [local testing](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/cloud-sql/postgres/sqlalchemy#launch-proxy-with-unix-domain-socket), I also used the Unix Sockets connection:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=$DB_SOCKET_DIR --instances=$INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME --credential_file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS &
```

When your Cloud Run service connects to a public Cloud SQL instance, it's [using](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run#public-ip-default_1) the Unix Socket connection, and therefore the variables of `DB_HOST` and `DB_PORT` are not being utilized. Only during local testing which you say worked as expected.

Besides that, it's not clear in your code where `DB_INSTANCE_NAME` comes from (the instance connection name for your Cloud SQL instance). `DB_NAME` is the database name you are querying inside your Postgres instance (wasn't clear for me at first).

**main.py**

```python
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

db_user = os.environ["DB_USER"]
db_pass = os.environ["DB_PASS"]
db_name = os.environ["DB_NAME"]
db_socket_dir = os.environ.get("DB_SOCKET_DIR", "/cloudsql")
instance_connection_name = os.environ["INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"]
DB_URI = f"postgresql+pg8000://{db_user}:{db_pass}@/{db_name}?unix_sock={db_socket_dir}/{instance_connection_name}/.s.PGSQL.5432"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_URI

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Model to map to user table in postgres
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False, nullable=True)

#Fetches and displays a value from CloudSQL for testing
@app.route("/")
def hello_query():
    message = User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
    return "Hello world, message: {}!".format(message.fullname)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

**Deployment command (for testing only)**

```
gcloud run deploy cloudrunpostgres \
--add-cloudsql-instances=$INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME \
--update-secrets=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME:latest \
--update-secrets=DB_USER=DB_USER:latest \
--update-secrets=DB_PASS=DB_PASS:latest \
--update-secrets=DB_NAME=DB_NAME:latest \
--source . \
--service-account=$SERVICE_ACCT \
--max-instances=3 \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--region=us-central1
```

This worked both on localhost and deployed as a service, which I hope is useful as a reference in both the command and the code.

Note: I did install the `cloud-sql-python-connector`, since it also installs the `pg8000` driver as a dependency (in addition to installing `Flask`, `SQLALchemy` and `Flask-SQLAlchemy`)